# Publish CAN frame on topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to publish CAN data to a ROS topic.  I followed the talker tutorial and am using the suggestion on this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/213645/running-can-radar-on-ros-through-raspberry-pi-2/?comment=218160#post-id-218160

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "socketcan_interface/socketcan.h"
#include "socketcan_interface/threading.h"
#include "socketcan_interface/string.h"

void handleFrames(const can::Frame &f){
    // handle all frames
    LOG(can::tostring(f, true)); // lowercase: true
}
void handleFrame123(const can::Frame &f){
    // handle specific frame
    LOG("123? " << can::tostring(f, true)); // lowercase: true
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    can::ThreadedSocketCANInterface driver;
    if(!driver.init("can0", false)) return 1; // read own messages: false

    can::CommInterface::FrameListener::Ptr all_frames = driver.createMsgListener(handleFrames);
    can::CommInterface::FrameListener::Ptr one_frame = driver.createMsgListener(can::MsgHeader(0xFF32), handleFrame123); // handle only frames with CAN-ID 0x123

    ros::init(argc, argv, "data_raw");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher canbus_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("canbus", 1000);

    while (ros::ok())
    {
      std_msgs::String msg;
      std::stringstream ss;

      ss << all_frames;
      msg.data = ss.str();
      canbus_pub.publish(msg);

      //ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

      //ROS_INFO("%s", std::cout<<"all_frames is of type: "<<typeid(all_frames).name()<<std::endl);

      ros::spinOnce();
    }

  driver.shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

This line `LOG(can::tostring(f, true)` will print the CAN frame to the console like:

```
00063200#8000010100000000
00061200#0000010100000000
00063200#8000010100000000
00EF0900#0000000000000000
00061200#0000010100000000
00063200#8000010100000000
00061200#0000010100000000
00063200#8000010100000000
```

This line `canbus_pub.publish(msg)` prints to a rostopic canbus but no frame data:

```
---
data: 0x1e9db80
---
data: 0x1e9db80
```

How do I get the individual CAN frames to print to the topic?

Thanks,

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218198/publish-can-frame-on-topic/) by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2015-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2015-09-25**:
This code cannot compile! Please move `std_msgs::String msg;` into `handleFrames`.
The CAN-IDs in the LOG outputs look strange, too. I have to check `can::tostring` next week.

**Comment by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on 2015-09-25**:
I found this package.  Maybe it is a better place to start.
https://github.com/juancamilog/canbus_interface

Haven't got it working yet.

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2015-11-13**:
Any good news about this? Please advice me how to us it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This interface works well.  I haven't tried sending but it will publish CAN data to a topic.

https://github.com/juancamilog/canbus_interface

---

Originally posted by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) with karma: 90 on 2015-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khairulizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25088/khairulizwan/) on 2015-11-13**:
Any good news about this? Please advice me how to us it...

**Comment by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on 2016-04-26**:
This package has been updated to include a new CanFrame2 msg that includes a bool for extended. https://github.com/jeremy-a/canbus_interface

**Comment by [yaovincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27315/yaovincent/) on 2016-06-28**:
I am a newbie. I installed the package,but I am sure it been installed correctly.
I used rosrun to find the command, but i can not find any command about the packet.
Any command to prove the packet is installed correctly?